# В каком формате лучше всего выгружать модели в three.js

Tags: three.js

В каком формате лучше всего выгружать модели в three.js? Отдельно текстура+ obj + mtl или может быть лучше в формате fbx? 
Хотелось бы чтобы это меньше весило и была оптимизация какая-то

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос "какой формат лучше?", ответ: "тот, что больше вам подходит".

Следует знать о различиях некоторых форматов, а в частности - `.obj` и `.fbx`:

**.OBJ**:

1. Формат является открытым.
2. Формат является текстовым.

*Из плюсов*:

1. Открытый - свободное использование где угодно. Не нужно волноваться, что вы что-то нарушаете.
2. Текстовый. Т.е. `human-readable`. Можете открыть любым блокнотом, посмотреть, что там записано.
3. Простой. Можно за полчаса написать свой загрузчик, ну и т.д...

*Из минусов*:

1. Из-за того, что формат текстовый, загружается загрузчиками он довольно долго.
2. У формата есть определенная спецификация, однако одну и ту же геометрию можно представить в формате по-разному. Кто-то при записи в формат соблюдает все правила и пишет название модели, группы, в общем, все как положено. Кто-то записывает лишь треугольные полигоны, а кто-то записывает их многоугольниками. Поэтому часто можно встретить случаи, когда отдельный экземпляр одним загрузчиком грузится хорошо, а другим - с какими-то дикими артефактами.
3. Формат не поддерживает анимации. Ну представьте, у вас текстом одна модель будет занимать кучу места, а анимации - так вообще!

**.FBX**:

1. Формат является проприетарным и недокументированным.
2. Формат является бинарным.
3. Данный формат изначально был предназначен для "обмена" 3D-геометрией различных приложений, работающих с 3D. Насколько мне известно, при экспорте формата в тот же Unity последний парсит формат и сохраняет в каком-то внутреннем формате, т.е. в конечных файлах вашей игры `.fbx` уже не будет.

*Из плюсов*:

1. Думаю, все (назовем их "официальные") реализации загрузчиков этого формата будут работать как подобает, ведь об этом заботится компания Autodesk.
2. Формат бинарный, занимает мало места и быстро загружается.
3. Формат поддерживает анимации.

*Из минусов*:

1. Формат не поймет человек, открыв его в текстовом редакторе.
2. Формат довольно сложный.
3. Из-за того, что формат проприетарный, использование может быть затруднено...

**Заключение**

В целом, если подытожить: если вы можете найти хорошую реализацию `.fbx` и вам ничего не мешает использовать именно этот формат, то используйте его. У вас будет и приемлимая скорость загрузки, и малое количество занятого дискового места.

И да. Насколько мне известно, `three.js` предлагает поддержку моделей, сохраненных в `.json` формате. Так почему бы не воспользоваться такой возможностью? Думаю, у них имеются какие-то утилиты для преобразования различных форматов в `.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о выгрузке из разных программ типа Blender, то я бы погодил с форматом `.obj`. Так как все идет к тому, что в скором времени экспортер для этого формата будет выведен из состава дистрибутива Three.js и поддержка будет на правлена на форматы `FBX` и `glTF`.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12903